# Is Craft's search() case-insensitive?

Tags: search

Is Craft's [Search](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/searching) case-insensitive?

(And is there a way to toggle case-sensitivity on/off?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the underlying MySQL collation of the database and the tables Craft is searching against.  The MySQL 5.1 rules surrounding this can be found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/case-sensitivity.html

There isn't anything in Craft where you can toggle the case sensitivity of searches.

**Update:**

Turns out I was completely wrong on this. Case sensitive searches *would* rely on the database's underlying collation if Craft didn't normalize all search keywords to lowercase first.